# how to define this array on bash

Tags: arrays, bash, syntax

what is wrong with this line

```
Array$j[$i]="10"
```

when I use this line on my bash script, I got this error: **command not found**.
I think the problem refers to $j. because when I change above to

```
Array[$i]="10"
```

I do not get any error. But I need this declaration. because on my bash file. I have to define 
multiple array with this name

> Array1, Array2 , Array3 and ... .

How to chage this line to work correctly:

```
Array$j[$i]="10"
```

Ps. j is an loop index. and it give number j=1, j=2, ...

Comment: was able to usethe 'let' command as well...let Array$j[$i]=10; tempvar=Array$j[$i];echo ${!tempvar}; http://stackoverflow.com/a/16524913

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not about arrays but variables in general, as you can not do `j=foo; $j=bar` to get a variable `foo` with value `bar`.

You can use `eval` or `declare`, at the beginning of the line, to make the substitution before setting the value.

Example:

```
for i in 1 2 3; do
  for j in 1 2; do
    eval array$j[$i]=foobar

    varname=array$j[$i]
    echo ${!varname}
  done
done
```

Comment: whould you please add echo to the for ? I mean please add echo array$j[$i]. thanks

Comment: @alex I just did it (but user000001 already gave the way : indirection).

Comment: `declare` is safer (if only to avoid bad habits) than `eval` in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Use associative arrays if supported (Bash 4.0+):

```
declare -A Array
Array[$j,$i]=10
echo "${Array[$j,$i]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `declare -A` to declare the array. This means that the value of `$j` is expanded before the assignment is made:

```
$ j=2
$ declare -A array$j="10"
$ echo "${array2[0]}"
10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an indirect reference:

```
$ Array1[0]=10
$ echo "${Array1[0]}"
10
$ j=1
$ arr=Array${j}
$ echo "${!arr[0]}"
10
```